# Mono CSharp Evaluator : creating two Action<object> via two distinct Run() crashes

Tags: mono

I'm trying to embed mono in a c++ executable, and mono crashes on the second evaluator.Run(..) as below. Any idea of what I missed ?

Using mono 3.0.3.

EmbeddedMonoTest.cpp

```
// EmbeddedMonoTest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <mono/metadata/debug-helpers.h>
#include <mono/metadata/exception.h>
#include <mono/jit/jit.h>
#include <mono/metadata/assembly.h>
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MonoDomain* domain = mono_jit_init_version ("ClassLibrary1", "v4.0.30319");
    MonoAssembly* assembly  = mono_domain_assembly_open (domain, "ClassLibrary1.dll");  
    mono_assembly_get_image(mono_domain_assembly_open (domain, "Mono.CSharp.dll")); 
    MonoImage* image = mono_assembly_get_image (assembly);
    MonoClass* klass = mono_class_from_name(image, "ClassLibrary1", "Class1");
    MonoMethod* test = mono_class_get_method_from_name(klass, "Test", 0);
    mono_runtime_invoke(test, NULL, NULL, NULL); 
    return 0;
}
```

Class1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Mono.CSharp;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void Test()
        {

            var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Class1));

            CompilerSettings settings = new CompilerSettings();
            ReportPrinter printer = new ConsoleReportPrinter();
            CompilerContext context = new CompilerContext(settings, printer);
            Evaluator evaluator = new Evaluator(context);
            evaluator.ReferenceAssembly(assembly);
            evaluator.Run("using System; using ClassLibrary1;");
            evaluator.Run("Action<object> action = args => {{ 'x'.ToString(); }}; ");
            evaluator.Run("Action<object> b = args => {{ 'x'.ToString(); }}; ");
        }
    }
}
```

The error :

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0274b00d in EmbeddedMonoTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

Comment: Have you tried running the same Managed piece of code without the bootstrapping native piece ? The reason I'm asking is because in .NET (not sure about Mono though) it would have been mandatory to do this also: evaluator.ReferenceAssembly(typeof(Action).Assembly);  (guess that would be System.dll) and it would be of great help to everyone if you tested just the managed part (without the native part) so as that you know clearly if that is ok by itself

Comment: I mean.. you're doing both "Voodoo"
 and "Conducting classical music" at the same time :). And something went wrong and you're not sure which of the endeavors malfunctioned. Conduct the classical music first :)

Comment: It wouldn't go through the first Run(Action...) if System.dll wasn't referenced.